# API Manager : Permissions on Application on the Store

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, api-manager

i'm working on API Manager 1.9.0 and i have a little question on the configuration of permissions on the Store. I am working with organizations and shared applications. So i wonder if it is possible to keep a user from deleting or editing an [shared application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsV4f.png) ? 
I tried to manipulate the permissions of the role in the management console but i can't figure out how to do it. there is no permission on the applications ..

Comment: Im not clear with your use case. " So i wonder if it is possible to keep a user from deleting or editing an shared application ? " What you exactly want to do?

Comment: For example, if an user 1 create an application, this application will be shared among his organisation. And an user 2 (from the same organisation) will be able to delete or edit this shared application. is it possible to remove his right to delete or edit this application ?

Answer (score 0):

As per the requirement you can define set of user roles against the user.
Then define set of APIs which corresponds do those roles. 
When you define new APIs, Under Visibility you can go for Restricted by roles and give the role which you have defined earlier. End of the day only the users in this roles will be able to access these APIs.
Now bind these APIs to applications. From that you can ensure that your application only accessed by the users in certain roles which resides in the user store.Then you able to give permission for the applications ..

Thanks,